# Identity in Lawvere and Schanuel's Conceptual mathematics

Tags: category-theory

Is this a typo in *Conceptual Mathematics* by  Lawvere and Schanuel? [image: Screenshot]

Shouldn't identity law 1b be on $f$, not $g$, like this?

$1_B \circ f = f $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$